# Хочу нарисовать фрактал в pygame, не отображает изображение, на секунду моргает черным и потом белый экран

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
 
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

pygame.init()
 
W = 1200
H = 600
 
sc = pygame.display.set_mode((W, H))
pygame.display.set_caption("Множества Жюлиа")
sc.fill(WHITE)
 
FPS = 30        # число кадров в секунду
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

c = complex(-1)
P = 200                     # размер [2*P+1 x 2*P+1]
scale = P / 2               # масштабный коэффициент
n_iter = 100

for y in range(-P, P):
    for x in range(-P, P):
        a = x / scale
        b = y / scale
        z = complex(a, b)
        n = 0
        for n in range(n_iter):
            z = z**2 + c
            if abs(z) > 2:
                break
 
        if n == n_iter-1:
            r = g = b = 0
        else:
            r = (n % 2) * 32 + 128
            g = (n % 4) * 64
            b = (n % 2) * 16 + 128
 
        pygame.draw.circle(sc, (r, g, b), (x + P, y + P), 0)
        
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
            
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас в строчке:

```
pygame.draw.circle(sc, (r, g, b), (x + P, y + P), 0)
```

последним параметром стоит "0". а это, в соответствии с доками:

```
circle(surface, color, center, radius)
```

Радиус вашего круга. То есть все круги у вас получаются с радиусом "0". поставьте другое значение.

Comment: Заработало, спасибо